Sveltekit server side - Fetching data from localhost - Error fetching data: TypeError: fetch failed (ENOTFOUND)
I am having issues to try fetching data from my laravel api running locally.
In my +layout.server.js file I have this code:
const endpoint = "http://api.laravel.localhost";

export async function load() {
    let url = `${endpoint}/auth/me` 
    try {
        const options = {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'method': "GET"
            }
        };

        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
}

Then the error I got:
Error fetching data: TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11731:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async load (/home/codebunt/svelte-app/src/routes/app/+layout.server.js:27:26)
    at async Module.load_server_data (/home/codebunt/svelte-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/load_data.js:57:17)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async Module.render_data (/home/codebunt/svelte-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/data/index.js:111:17)
    at async resolve (/home/codebunt/svelte-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:402:17)
    at async Module.respond (/home/codebunt/svelte-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:282:20)
    at async file:///home/codebunt/svelte-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:510:22 {
  cause: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.laravel.localhost
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
    errno: -3008,
    code: 'ENOTFOUND',
    syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
    hostname: 'api.laravel.localhost'
  }
}

This occurs only for local, externals endpoint is working fine.
I also tried using the IP:
http://127.0.0.1/laravel/public/api
In the svelte.config.js I tried:
kit: {
        
        csrf: {
            checkOrigin: false
        }
}


The endpoint is not formatted properly. Change http:/api.laravel.localhost; to http://api.laravel.localhost;

Sorry, that was a typing mistake, my code is correct with the  http://
